# I want a PHP for loop that goes to certain number and again starts from zero

Tags: php, for-loop

I want a PHP for loop that goes to certain number say "23" and again starts from "0".
Actually I want for the listing of time in 24 hours format and suppose a case is: I have to show time from 9 AM to 2 AM (i.e 9,10,11,12,13,14,...........23,0,1,2)

```
$i= range(0,23);//it doest work as it creates an array containing a range of elements
$start_time = 9;
$end_time = 2;
for ($i = $start_time ; $i<= $end_time ; $i++)
{
    echo $i;
}
```

Please suggest a way.

Comment: your endtime is lower than your starttime.

Comment: @Recode ...hence the question.

Comment: if you have a range that is an array, you might consider using foreach?

Comment: @Nanne I think the array was just an attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: yes, but not per se a bad one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everybody for your help, using your ideas I got my work done.
Here is the code that actually worked.

```
$start_time = some_dynamic_value;
$end_time = some_dynamic_value;
$i= $start_time;
$flag = false;
if($start_time > $end_time)
$flag = true;
while ($i <= $end_time || $flag)
{
        echo $i;

        if($i == 24)
        {
                $i= 0;
                $flag = false;
        }
        $i++;
}
```

Comment: So much code for something and so much extra processes and variables for something that is rather simple.  Why did you go this route over any of the others provided?

Comment: what I wanted was a dropdown list of available times(based on store location timings) for a pizza store and It could be anytime in 24 hours format, others answer didn't serve my requirement exactly.

Comment: Why did you take such a verbose route rather than a simpler and smaller base for this?  That's a lot of code to just display a list of numbers.  I'm just curious ^^

Comment: There are more than 20 stores and for each stores, different timings are there for each days of a week and I needed to show the listed timings only according to day. And store timings are like 8:00 Hrs to 20:00 Hrs for mon, 8:00 Hrs t0 8:00 Hrs for tue, 9:00 Hrs to 2:00 Hrs for wed, 20:00 Hrs to 6:00 Hrs for thu and so on......Dynamic dropdown for date is there aswell and based on that the timing dropdown will come after selecting one one of the dates.... Thats why

Comment: Ahh. Ok.  Thank you for taking the time to satiate my curiosity. If I could create a function that kind of worked like `range` does with the rollover at midnight for you, is that something you'd be interested in?  Just to help with usability in the future. ^^

Comment: ohh..that would be really great and will be helpful for others aswell.

Answer (score 2):

Since your use-case mentions time-sensitive information you might be best off learning to use the `date` and `strtotime` functions (or the `DateTime` classes):

```
$time = strtotime('2013-09-14 02:00');
$endTime = strtotime('2013-09-15 09:00');

while ($time <= $endTime) {
    echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time)."\n";
    $time = strtotime('+1 hour', $time);
}

// 2013-09-14 02:00:00
// 2013-09-14 03:00:00
// 2013-09-14 04:00:00
// 2013-09-14 05:00:00
// etc.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$start_time = 9;
$end_time = 2;

$end_time += ($end_time < $start_time) ?  24 : 0;

for ($i = $start_time; $i<= $end_time; $i++) {
    echo ($i % 24);
}
```

Reason, the line `$end_time += ($end_time < $start_time) ?  24 : 0;` checks to see if the end time is less than the start time (which we assume means the next day), and if it is, it adds 24 hours to it. The line `$i %24` is the modulus operator which will divide the number and give the remainder, so if it's `25`, it will give you `1` back.  Note that all hours being worked with will need to be in 24 hour format to use this method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the modulo to deduct 24 from numbers when they're greater than 23.

```
$start_time = 9;
$end_time = 2;
for( $i = $start_time; $i % 24 != $end_time; $i++ )
{
    echo $i % 24;
}
```

Note that you need to be careful with this; if `$end_time` is greater than 23 it will be stuck in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this its working

```
<?php
$i= range(0,23);//it doest work as it creates an array containing a range of elements
$start_time = 9;
$end_time = 2;
$max_value=23;
if($start_time>=$end_time)
{
    for ($i = $start_time ; $i<= $max_value; $i++)
    {
        echo $i;
    }
    for($i=0; $i<=$end_time; $i++)  
    {
    echo $i;    
    }
}
else
{
    for ($i = $start_time ; $i<= $max_value; $i++)
    {
        echo $i;
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Again late to Answer** , Try this

```
<?php
$start_time = 20;
$end_time = 10;

$maxTime=23;
$minTime=0;


for ($i = $minTime ; $i<=$maxTime - abs($start_time-$end_time) ; $i++)
{
    $validTime= $start_time +  ($i % $maxTime);
    $validTime= $validTime>$maxTime?$validTime-$maxTime:$validTime;
    echo $validTime;

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be a `for` loop?
You can try this

```
function hours($range, $recurse = true, $end = array())
{
  foreach($range as $time)
  {
    echo $time . "\n";
  }

  if($recurse && sizeof($end) > 0)
  {
    $range = range($end['start'], $end['end']);
    hours($range, false);
  }
}

$range = range(9,23);
$end = array('start' => 0, 'end' => 2);
hours($range, true, $end);
```

Comment: You created a complex function for the issue with a hard-coded end time?

Comment: @Jon just an example ... a bad one if you want

Comment: Examples are good, but your code here should be portable, not just usable in a single-instance.  Also, you shouldn't use a function if it won't take in to account all variable information (ie the `$start_time` and `$end_time`), which we must assume are variable as they are assigned to variables in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out. Hope this helps

```
$start_time = 9;
$end_time = 2;

$flag = 1;
while($flag) [
    echo $start_time . "<br>";        
    $start_time++;
    if ($start_time == 23) { $start_time = 0; }
    if ($start_time == $end_time) {
        $flag = 0;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Maybe better to use [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php):

```
$hours = 8;
for ($i=1; $i<=8; $i++){
  echo 'TIME1 = '.date("Y-m-d H:i:s",mktime (20+$i,15,18,06,05,2013)).'<br>';
}
```

or better [DateTime class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php):

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2013-06-05 20:15:18');
$hours = 8;
for ($i=0; $i<8; $i++){
  $date->add(new DateInterval('PT1H'));
  echo 'TIME2 = '.$date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s').'<br>';
}
```